# pass JTextField from class to ArrayList class

Tags: java, arraylist, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I'm trying to pass the value from a JTextField from my GUI (main) class to an ArrayList from another class by pressing a button (action listener).

I tried a few things but couldnt really work it out.

This is my GUI class with the textfield I want to pass:

```
private JButton button1;
private JTextField textfield9;

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            // here I want it to be added into the Arraylist after button click
        }
});
```

This is what I have in the other Class with an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> list;
public Administratie()
{
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void addToArray(String s)
{
    list.add(s);
}
```

I don't think need I need to post any other code than this. Tell me if you need more or all of it.
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

you pass `textfield9.getText()`'s value to `Administratie#addToArray()` :

here is the simple demo :

gui.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
public class gui extends JFrame{
private JButton button1;
private JTextField textfield9;
private JTextArea result;
public int i=0;

public class1(){

   super("");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());

   button1 = new JButton("button1");
   textfield9 = new JTextField(10);
   result = new JTextArea(30,30);


   Administratie administratie = new Administratie();

   button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    String temResult ="";
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
       {
           // pass the value to Administratie 
           administratie.addToArray(textfield9.getText());

           // get the value from Administratie 
            temResult += administratie.getList().get(i++)+"\n";
            result.setText(temResult);

       }
});


add(textfield9,BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(button1,BorderLayout.WEST);
add(new JScrollPane(result), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

setVisible(true);
setSize(400,400);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   new gui();
} 
}
```

Administratie.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Administratie{
ArrayList<String> list;
public Administratie()
{
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void addToArray(String s)
{
    list.add(s);
}

public List<String> getList(){
    return this.list;
}
  }
```

Comment: @Fe Thank you for the answer, it works, but the it's showing them between [], cant I make them line undereach other with a \n. And I dont quite understand why you would need a i++ thhere|?

Comment: @user3688895, take a look at my update on gui class above , to get you better understanding about it :D, i have concatenated the result with ("\n") , and the i++ it just, think it like an index of the list , to access the elements of the list (which are values that you pass to the list)